# What is the best database for android?

Tags: android

I'm new here and junior programmer. 
I would create a database for an application that I am creating and I would like to know which recommends android applications.

Thank you!!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving data to a database is ideal for repeating or structured data, such as contact information. This class assumes that you are familiar with SQL databases in general and helps you get started with **SQLite** databases on Android. The **APIs** you'll need to use a database on Android are available in the **android.database.sqlite** package.

[This](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) is the official documentation.

see this also 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 0):

try [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Android has [builtin support](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html).

Sample [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)